# Python: fill hollow object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a script to calculate the volume of any random shaped 3D object. I don't care if the object is hollow or not I need to calculate its total volume. 
The data model I have is a 3D table (histogram of pixels) with ones and zeros. ones are evidently where the object is and zero where we have nothing. to calculate the volume of a well filled object it's as easy as summing all the pixels that contains one and multiply by the pixel volume. 
On the other hand, the main difficulty remains where we have a hollow object, so we have zeros surrounded by ones. Therefore applying the straightforward method I described herein is not valid anymore. What we need to do is fill all the object area with ones. here is a 2D example so you can understand What i mean

a 2D table :

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I need to transform it to this

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use [`scipy`](http://www.scipy.org/) you can do this in one line with [`binary_fill_holes`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes.html#scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes). **And this works in n-dimensions.** With your example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
shape=np.array([
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    ])
shape[ndimage.binary_fill_holes(shape)] = 1
#Output:
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Many thanks for your swift and kind reply, I've tried your script and it works. Still It doesn't work for 3D histogram data. Actually The example I gave is a 2D matrix, in no means I am going to use 2D data. My aim is to work with 3D object so my historgrams are 3D tables. So I need to detect 3D holes and fill them but not 2D hole in a sheets
Best regards and

Comment: @Bachir AOUN - hi, I've used this with 3D data (3d binary arrays), and it worked fine, but the hollow object must be closed in each dimension, and it must be binary. Perhaps you should post a simple example of data that is closer to what you are using.

Comment: import math

radius = 5
points = []
inc = math.pi * (3 - math.sqrt(5))
offset = 2 / float(n)
for k in range(int(n)):
    y = k * offset - 1 + (offset / 2)
    r = math.sqrt(1 - y*y)
    phi = k * inc
    points.append([math.cos(phi)*r* radius, y*radius, math.sin(phi)*r*radius])

resolution = 0.05
ballRadius = 0.2
rMax = np.max(np.abs(data)) + 2*ballRadius
histBins = ceil(1.0*rMax/resolution)
histRange = [-rMax , rMax]

hist, edges = np.histogramdd(data, bins = (histBins,histBins, histBins), range =[histRange,histRange, histRange])

The hist is the data.

Comment: @Bachir AOUN - thats not a simple example! and whats `n` and whats `data`??

Comment: Dear fraxel,
Thank you for your help, I have fixed the problem. I appreciate your kind replies.
Yes i know it's not a simple example, i've tried to make as close as possible from my real data. My data are atoms coordinates actually ...
sincerely yours

Answer (score 2):

A standard [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) should be extensible to three dimensions. From Wikipedia, the 2-d version in outline:

```
1. If the color of node is not equal to target-color, return.
 2. Set the color of node to replacement-color.
 3. Perform Flood-fill (one step to the west of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the east of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the north of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the south of node, target-color, replacement-color).
 4. Return.
```

Notice that in step 3. you are keeping track of all the adjacent cells. If you change this to find all adjacent cells in 3-d and run as before it should work nicely.

Comment: What about diagonal cells, shouldn't they be considered, too?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure they should. Wouldn't that allow the fill to pass through a single-pixel 45 degree line?

Answer (score 1):

```
matrix=[
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    ]

def fill (x,y):
    global matrix
    if ( x==len (matrix)
             or y==len (matrix[0])
             or x==-1
             or y==-1
             or matrix[x][y]==1 ):
            return
    else:
        matrix[x][y]=1
        fill (x+1,y)
        fill (x-1,y)
        fill (x,y+1)
        fill (x,y-1)

fill (4,4)

for i in matrix:
    print i
```

Comment: shouldn't it be (x, y+1) instead of (x+1, y+1) if you follow [this algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11376512/4279)

Comment: Would be a simpler to just say `if not matrix[x][y]:` then the indented suite starting with `matrix[x][y] = 1` and so on (i.e. no `else:`).

Comment: In general this code does not handle the edge conditions properly (where a computed x and/ore y are invalid because one or both are outside the given matrix) -- even so this doesn't occur with the test case.

Comment: It fills the component of the initial point (4,4) in this case. Otherwise, called with (1,1), it fills the external component

Answer (score 1):

Not intuitive and hard to read, but compact:

```
matrix = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
          [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

ranges = [1 in m and range(m.index(1), len(m)-list(reversed(m)).index(1)) or None for m in matrix]
result = [[ranges[j] is not None and i in ranges[j] and 1 or 0 for i,a in enumerate(m)] for j,m in enumerate(matrix)]

result
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about something like filling a [voxel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voxel) shape, why can't you just do something like this (take it as pseudocode example for the simplified 2D case, as I don't know what data structure you're using - maybe a [numpy.array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)? - so I'm just taking a hypothetical "list of lists as a matrix" and I don't take in consideration the problem of modifying an iterable while traversing it etc.):

```
for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
    last_filled_voxel_j = false
    for j, voxel in enumerate(row):
        if voxel:
            if last_filled_voxel != false:
                fill_matrix(matrix, i, last_filled_voxel_j, j)
            last_filled_voxel_j = j
```

...assuming that `fill_matrix(matrix, row, column_start, column_end)` just fills the row of voxels between and not including `column_start` and `column_end`.

I guess this is probably not the answer you're looking for, but can you expand what thing different than what I pseudocoded before you actually need to do so we can be of more help?

Comment: yes, I'm basically describing the simplest reduction of flood-fill, so the wikipedia article also linked by the answer of @Alex_Wilson is probably the answer you're looking for